# POST Calling Apex Method not displaying showing in Dev Console

Tags: apex, developer-console, webhooks

I have an exposed apex class and it is working becaues it's inserting test records. However, I'm not able to see anything in the dev console where the apex method was called.

Is there a specific configuration you need to have on your dev console to see exposed apex methods called?

Comment: do you mean logs are not showing up?

Comment: how are you calling the apex method to test?

Answer (score 3):

Click on Debug, and uncheck Show My Current Logs Only. You'll get logs from other sessions, not just the current browser session.

Comment: Thanks sfdc fox. It was actually that I had to do a couple things. Will post the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

@sfdcfox is correct that Show Current Logs Only is an option that needs to be unchecked. However, you also need to do a couple things.

1. Make sure your site that is being referenced by the webhook has access to the Apex Class. This is done in your sites public access settings.
2. Make sure that you also have a debug log set up for the site guest user that is running the method when it is called by the webhook.

Thanks for the help. This community is great!